# Not able to query custom field on CaseMilestone

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud, entitlements, casemilestone, entitlement-process

I have created a custom field on **CaseMilestone**, But i am not able to do a query that particular field.

is that a restriction from salesforce or i am missing something ?
[image]
**Regards**
Nirmallya

[image]

Comment: Did you check the field-level security to make sure it was visible?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you are not able to perform a query, is there an error you receive?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have access to the field - check field-level security. That's the most common reason you cannot query a field.

Comment: I do have proper FLS, still i am not able to make the query.